# Can a TFS Database project that is out of date be updated from a database that is up to date

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, tfs

A TFS Database project has gone out of date because of a TFS machine crash. I have a database that is up to date. The changes are all in the tables and views. Can I update the project from the database and how would I go about doing this.

Comment: Look at the MSDN documentation for disaster recovery. You'll have to restore the databases from synchronized backup sets.

Comment: What's your TFS database project mean？ Are you meaning the database projects that come with VS 2010 out of the box  or [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) Database project

Comment: This is a SSDT database that was under source control at the time of the crash. Amazingly, and it only occurred to me a few hours ago, I was able to find the database project source in the Build Drop that MSBuild creates when a web project is deployed. This does of course not solve the issue of "what about the history of the project".

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try with manually bring the changes in using the **schema compare** in SSDT, you can set the database as the source and project as the destination and choose what you drop, update and import.

More details please refer  this  tutorial: [How to: Use Schema Compare to Compare Different Database Definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

For the old datebase project please refer: [How to: Import Updates from a Database into the Database Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833173%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I am going to try using these hints as soon as I have caught up with the backlog this disaster has caused. My sincere thanks for the input.